# how to verify a user update database table only once using foreach and if statement

Tags: php

In the MySQL database table which is keeping questions of the forum i have a field which is also keeping user ID's who has liked the question or not, e.g when the button like clicked is updating the column **likes** in this format 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .etc... I would like to verify that the user can only like/dislike one question once since am new to php i was hoping to use `foreach` and `if` statement to check either the user ID is already in the database column likes/dislikes if not update if available `echo` error

If i use the first code am not getting anything although the data exits in the database.

```
$nocast = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$likes = ("$row[likes]");
$dislikes = ("$row[dislikes]");
foreach($likes as $voters)
    if($likes == $nocast)
        echo("you already voted");
exit;
```

And if I use the second am getting what I want but the problem I can not directly enter the numbers.

```
$nocast = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$likes = ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5");
foreach($likes as $voters)
    if($likes == $nocast)
        echo("you already voted");
exit;
```

Can one help me how do I go about it I don't need to create two tables and if this is wrong how to do it? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one user can vote for many questions and one question can be voted by many users, you have a many to many relationship. So, you would better use two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You have the basic syntax for accessing array keys wrong here:

```
$likes = ("$row[likes]");
```

That should be:

```
$likes = $row['likes'];
```

This then leaves the question of whether that variable actually holds the array you want, which we can't tell without seeing more code. Running `var_dump($likes);` would soon show you.

Comment: If the field is comma-separated, you will also need to `explode()` the string to an array before you loop through it.

Comment: @IMSop i cant really get what you mean 'var_dump($likes);'

Comment: @madcoder What's to get? You add that line to your script, PHP tells you what's in the variable. If it's an array with the values you want, good; if not, then you need to change something, such as using explode to separate out items from a string, as showdev says.

Comment: @IMSop OK i get it fine and also little help here, my user id is `id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , when am transferring the ID to other fields which also require its ID to be `id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , in what data type should i keep the user id  to avoid duplicate entry